# Using process.start in a wpf application to invoke another wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, process, argument-passing, calling-convention

I am trying to invoke one wpf application from another wpf application. 
The invoking wpf application makes the call

```
ProcessStartInfo BOM = new ProcessStartInfo();

BOM.FileName = @"D:\WPFAPPLICATION.exe";

BOM.Arguments = temp;

Process.Start(BOM);
```

Now in the invoked application, I try to retrieve the argument passed using

```
  string arguments =Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.Arguments;
```

However the arguments are not passed. why is this??

I also tried an alternative method where in:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    public static String[] mArgs;

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            mArgs = e.Args;


        }
    }
    }
    }
```

However this did not work either!!!
Please HELP!!

Comment: Are you sure `temp` actually has the value you expect? Also i've had problem retrieving arguments from the start info before when using Powershell, forgot what the problem was, but i think the application still runs with the right arguments, it may just not be preserved in the start info.

Comment: Im sure temp holds the desired value. But I dont think its being passed to the wpf application being called.

Comment: @Sana, can you show the declaration of `temp`?

Comment: var temp = string.Empty;
temp = Convert.ToString(values[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Im very sure temp holds the required value as I have added a watch and monitered the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally found a solution to my question if anyones interested.
While in the calling application I maintained the same code I previously used:

```
ProcessStartInfo BOM = new ProcessStartInfo();
BOM.FileName = @"D:\WPFAPPLICATION.exe";
BOM.Arguments = temp;
Process.Start(BOM);
```

In the called application in order to receive arguments successfully I simply had to :

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder strbuilder= new System.Text.StringBuilder();


    foreach (String arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
    {
        strbuilder.AppendLine(arg);
        barcode = arg;
    }
    psnfo = strbuilder.ToString();
```

I was not handling the arguments passed to the process in the correct manner

so upon displaying psnfo

The code returns :

```
 D:\WPFAPPLICATION.exe temp
```

Source : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/386260/Using-process-start-in-a-wpf-application-to-invoke

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) class to get the commandline arguments.

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
```

or use the string[] that is passed to your main method of your WPF Application (App.xaml.cs).

```
public partial class App : Application {

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        string[] args = e.Args;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
The call

```
string arguments =Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.Arguments;
```

will not return any value. See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx) entry

> If you did not use the Start method to start a process, the StartInfo property does not reflect the parameters used to start the process. For example, if you use GetProcesses to get an array of processes running on the computer, the StartInfo property of each Process does not contain the original file name or arguments used to start the process.

Comment: but i did use the start method in the calling application to start the process

Comment: I used a similar method as suggested by you previously(see the edit)...But that didnt work either.

Comment: @Sana but not from inside the started application

Comment: I tried string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs previously aswell..Im at a dead end!!

Comment: but not from inside the started application...sorry I dont get it..what?I added that in the application being called

Comment: @Sana, that's exactly the problem. You've got two processes, which obviously don't share variables; each has its own instance of that `Process` object. The object in your first process (the one that calls `Start`) would have the `StartInfo`. The object in your second process would not, because it's getting a `Process` instance for an *already-running* process. `GetCurrentProcess` is equivalent to `GetProcesses` in that regard: you're not starting a *new* process, you're getting an *existing* process and so don't have `StartInfo` (per the MSDN docs quoted at the end of this answer).

Comment: oh okay...I didnt think of that...Sorry Im pretty new to all this..do you have any ideas as to how I could proceed from here??

Comment: Is there any way I can pass the arguments between the calling process and called process.